# How to make python program extensible

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of line of codes like these in a row in my program:

```
str = str.replace('ten', '10s')
str = str.replace('twy', '20s')
str = str.replave('fy', '40s')
...
```

I want to make it such that I don't have to manually open my source file to add new cases. For example ('sy', '70'). I know I have to put all these in a function somehow, but I'd like to map cases that are not in my "mapper lib" from the command line. Configuration file maybe? how?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't name your variables after built-in functions. What if you need to call `str(123)` after that?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a config file in [json](http://www.json.org/) format like this:

```
[
    ["ten", "10s"],
    ["twy", "20s"],
    ["fy", "40s"]
]
```

Save it as 'replacements.json' and then use it this way:

```
import json

with open('replacements.json') as i:
    replacements = json.load(i)

text = 'ten, twy, fy'
for r in replacements:
    text = text.replace(r[0], r[1])
```

Then when you need to change the values just edit the replacements.json file without touching any Python code.

The format for you replacements file could be anything but json is easy to use and edit.

Comment: I'd probably just make a json file in the same directory and call the file to load up new entries. I'm still wondering if the dictionary might not be better suited for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution could be to put those in a file, read them in your program and do your replaces in a loop..

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, if it's a rarely changing thing you could consider doing it with a Python dict:

```
mappings = {
  'ten': '10s',
  'twy': '20s',
  'fy': '40s',
}

def replace(str_):
  for s, r in mappings.iteritems():
    str_.replace(s, r)
  return str_
```

Alternatively in a Text file (make sure you use a safe delimiter which isn't used in any of the keys!)

**mappings.txt**

```
ten|10s
twy|20s
fy|40s
```

And the Python part:

```
mappings = {}
for line in open('mappings.txt'):
    k, v = line.split('|', 1)
    mappings[k] = v
```

And use the replace from above :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use csv to store the replacements in a human-editable form in a file:

```
import csv

with open('replacements.csv', 'rb') as f:
     replacements = list(csv.reader(f))

for old, new in replacements:
    your_string = your_string.replace(old, new)
```

where `replacements.csv`:

```
ten,10s
twy,20s
fy,40s
```

It avoids unnecessary markup such as `"`, `[]` in the json format and allows a delimiter (`,`) to be present in a string itself unlike the plain text format [from @WoLpH's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809543/4279).

([live example](http://ideone.com/juKAi))